# How can I vertically align an equation within a multirow table?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, text

I'm building quite an involved table for one of my research papers, combining long equations and diagrams. Please can someone help with the vertical alignment of the right hand side columns to be positioned in the middle of each of the diagrams on the left?

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{@{}c|ccc|ccc@{}}
\toprule
Multi-layer Network & $l_i^k$                                          & $l_j^k$                                                                                                                                                      & $l_m^k$                                          & $l_i^{k'}$          & $l_j^{k'}$          & $l_m^{k'}$          \\ \midrule
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{Network1.png}                    & $\frac{1}{1-\beta}$                              & $\frac{1}{1-\beta}$                                                                                                                                          & $\frac{1}{1-\beta}$                              & $\frac{1}{1-\beta}$ & $\frac{1}{1-\beta}$ & $\frac{1}{1-\beta}$ \\ \midrule
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{Network2.png}                    & $\frac{1+\beta}{\frac{1}{2}-\psi-\beta^2}$       & $\frac{1+\beta}{\frac{1}{2}-\psi-\beta^2}$                                                                                                                   & $\frac{1}{1-\beta}$                              & $1+\beta l_i^k$     & $1+\beta l_j^k$     & $\frac{1}{1-\beta}$ \\ \midrule
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{Network3.png}                    & $\frac{1+\beta+\psi l_j^k}{\frac{1}{2}-\beta^2}$ & $\frac{\left ( 1+\beta \right )\left ( \frac{1}{2}-\beta^2+2\psi\right )}{\left ( \frac{1}{3} -\beta^2\right )\left ( \frac{1}{2} -\beta^2\right )-2\psi^2}$ & $\frac{1+\beta+\psi l_j^k}{\frac{1}{2}-\beta^2}$ & $1+\beta l_i^k$     & $1+\beta l_j^k$     & $1+\beta l_m^k$     \\ \midrule
                    &                                                  &                                                                                                                                                              &                                                  &                     &                     &                     \\ \midrule
                    &                                                  &                                                                                                                                                              &                                                  &                     &                     &                     \\ \midrule
                    &                                                  &                                                                                                                                                              &                                                  &                     &                     &                     \\ \midrule
                    &                                                  &                                                                                                                                                              &                                                  &                     &                     &                     \\ \midrule
                    &                                                  &                                                                                                                                                              &                                                  &                     &                     &                     \\ \midrule
                    &                                                  &                                                                                                                                                              &                                                  &                     &                     &                     \\ \midrule
                    &                                                  &                                                                                                                                                              &                                                  &                     &                     &                     \\ \midrule
                    &                                                  &                                                                                                                                                              &                                                  &                     &                     &                     \\ \midrule
                    &                                                  &                                                                                                                                                              &                                                  &                     &                     &                     \\ \midrule
                    &                                                  &                                                                                                                                                              &                                                  &                     &                     &                     \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions, in no particular order:

- Get rid of all vertical rules and replace (almost) all `\midrule` directivees with `\addlinespace` to get rid of lots of visual clutter.
- Switch from a `tabular` environment to an `array` environment and happily delete dozens and dozens of occurrences of `$` (inline math mode initiators and terminators) in one fell swoop.
- Load the `amsmath` package and encase the `\includegraphics` statements in `matrix` wrappers to vertically center the graphical images.
- Replace all instances of `\frac{1}{1-\beta}` with `1/(1-\beta)` and watch the fractional expressions immediately become more legible.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{booktabs,graphicx,amsmath}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\[
\begin{array}{@{} *{7}{c} @{}}
\toprule
\mbox{Multi-layer network} & l_i^k & l_j^k & l_m^k & l_i^{k'} & l_j^{k'} & l_m^{k'} \\
\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](r){1-1}
\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](lr){2-4} 
\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](l){5-7}
\addlinespace
\begin{matrix} 
   \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{Network1a.png} &
   \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{Network1b.png}
\end{matrix}
& 1/(1-\beta) & 1/(1-\beta) & 1/(1-\beta) 
& 1/(1-\beta) & 1/(1-\beta) & 1/(1-\beta) \\ 
\addlinespace
\begin{matrix} 
   \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{Network2a.png} &
   \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{Network2b.png}
\end{matrix}
& \frac{1+\beta}{\frac{1}{2}-\psi-\beta^2} 
& \frac{1+\beta}{\frac{1}{2}-\psi-\beta^2} 
& 1/(1-\beta) & 1+\beta l_i^k & 1+\beta l_j^k & 1/(1-\beta) \\ 
\addlinespace
\begin{matrix} 
   \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{Network3a.png} &
   \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{Network3b.png}
\end{matrix}
& \frac{1+\beta+\psi l_j^k}{\frac{1}{2}-\beta^2} 
& \frac{(1+\beta)\left( \frac{1}{2}-\beta^2+2\psi\right)}{
  \left( \frac{1}{3}-\beta^2\right)\left( \frac{1}{2}-\beta^2\right)-2\psi^2} 
& \frac{1+\beta+\psi l_j^k}{\frac{1}{2}-\beta^2} 
& 1+\beta l_i^k & 1+\beta l_j^k & 1+\beta l_m^k \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `adjustbox` and its `valign` key. I simplified your input by using

```
>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}
```

so you can spare all `$` symbols. Depending on your actual text width, you may be able to use `\small` instead of `\footnotesize`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp] % <--- NOT []

\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  c % the images
  *{6}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}} % the formulas
  @{}
}
\toprule
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} Multi-layer \\ Network \end{tabular} &
  l_i^k & l_j^k & l_m^k & l_i^{k'} & l_j^{k'} & l_m^{k'} \\
\midrule
\includegraphics[valign=c,width=1.6cm]{example-image} &
  \frac{1}{1-\beta} &
  \frac{1}{1-\beta} &
  \frac{1}{1-\beta} &
  \frac{1}{1-\beta} &
  \frac{1}{1-\beta} &
  \frac{1}{1-\beta} \\
\midrule
\includegraphics[valign=c,width=1.6cm]{example-image} &
  \frac{1+\beta}{\frac{1}{2}-\psi-\beta^2} &
  \frac{1+\beta}{\frac{1}{2}-\psi-\beta^2} &
  \frac{1}{1-\beta} &
  1+\beta l_i^k &
  1+\beta l_j^k &
  \frac{1}{1-\beta} \\
\midrule
\includegraphics[valign=c,width=1.6cm]{example-image} &
  \frac{1+\beta+\psi l_j^k}{\frac{1}{2}-\beta^2} &
  \frac{(1+\beta)(\frac{1}{2}-\beta^2+2\psi)}
       {(\frac{1}{3}-\beta^2)(\frac{1}{2} -\beta^2)-2\psi^2} &
  \frac{1+\beta+\psi l_j^k}{\frac{1}{2}-\beta^2} &
  1+\beta l_i^k &
  1+\beta l_j^k &
  1+\beta l_m^k \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `tabularray` and `adjustbox` packages, use common settings for image size and baseline:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htp] % <--- NOT []
\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth,valign=M}
\footnotesize
\begin{tblr}{hline{3-Y} = {dashed, 0.2pt},
              colsep = 3pt,
             colspec = {@{}  X[c,m] 
                        *{6}{Q[c,mode=dmath]}
                        @{}},
              rowsep = 3pt
            }
    \toprule
Multi-layer Network
    & l_i^k & l_j^k & l_m^k & l_i^{k'} & l_j^{k'} & l_m^{k'} \\
    \midrule
\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} &
  \frac{1}{1-\beta} &
  \frac{1}{1-\beta} &
  \frac{1}{1-\beta} &
  \frac{1}{1-\beta} &
  \frac{1}{1-\beta} &
  \frac{1}{1-\beta} \\
\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} &
  \frac{1+\beta}{\frac{1}{2}-\psi-\beta^2} &
  \frac{1+\beta}{\frac{1}{2}-\psi-\beta^2} &
  \frac{1}{1-\beta} &
  1+\beta l_i^k &
  1+\beta l_j^k &
  \frac{1}{1-\beta} \\
\adjincludegraphics{example-image-duck} &
  \frac{1+\beta+\psi l_j^k}{\frac{1}{2}-\beta^2} &
  \frac{(1+\beta)(\frac{1}{2}-\beta^2+2\psi)}
       {(\frac{1}{3}-\beta^2)(\frac{1}{2} -\beta^2)-2\psi^2} &
  \frac{1+\beta+\psi l_j^k}{\frac{1}{2}-\beta^2} &
  1+\beta l_i^k &
  1+\beta l_j^k &
  1+\beta l_m^k \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]